# Opening a PDF in a desktop application in Java

Tags: java, pdf

Is it possible to open or create a PDF file in a Java desktop application just like we can create text file?

From my search I got that it is possible only with web java. Is that true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) to do this. [Here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaPDF/article.html) is a nice tutorial.

Comment: thank,I am using netbeans 6.9.1.i already have the iText but don't know how to add it to the library.I have right click on Library and click on 'add JARs' but it does not work.plz help...

Comment: Hmm...great it is working,thanks load.i did not create the folder lib as mentioned in the examples before.Thanks you...

Answer (score 5):

To open an existing PDF file in the desktop default reader you can use the following code:

```
File pdf = new File("/path/to/your.pdf");
Desktop.getDesktop().open(pdf);
```

(needs Java 6)

Answer (score 1):

There is an OS PDF plugin for Netbeans at http://www.jpedal.org/support_siNetBeans.php

Answer (score 0):

You can not create PDF just like a normal Text file, you will need PDF Library to create one. Opening an existing PDF is possible like *a_horse_with_no_name* mentioned in his answer.

You can find some PDF Libraries [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries).